# Springboot - Create own Opentracing span with camel tracer

Tags: java, apache-camel, opentracing, jaeger

I have added the following annotation to my Spring Boot project:

`@CamelOpenTracing`

Which creates a span for every route my messages go through and it works perfect.

However, how do I create my own span? I want to add a span for when my messages goes to `onException` (add make error tag true).

I have tried unsuccessfully to get the tracer from the `camelContext` and create a span.

Comment: Hi Kevin. I don't think its easy out of the box. I suggest to log a JIRA ticket for this feature and then provide some description with suggestions for how you would like to be able to add custom span's to camel-opentracing.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a spans inside a camel process like this :

```
 from("queue:" + properties.getJmsEndpoint())
        .routeId("Jms-To-Ftp-" + properties.getFlowName())

        .setHeader(MessageHeaders.SENDER_ID, simple(properties.getApplication()))
            .process(exchange -> {
              //save original body for DLQ route
              String originalBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
              exchange.setProperty(MessageProperties.BACKUP_MESSAGE, originalBody);


              Span span = tracer.buildSpan("JmsMessage route").start();
              span.setTag("sender", properties.getApplication());
              span.setTag(MessageHeaders.DOCUMENT_ID, exchange.getIn().getHeader(MessageHeaders.DOCUMENT_ID).toString());
              span.setTag(MessageHeaders.PROCESS_TYPE_NAME, exchange.getIn().getHeader(MessageHeaders.PROCESS_TYPE_NAME).toString());

              span.log(ImmutableMap.of("file", originalBody));
              span.finish();

            })
       .to("queue:" + properties.getReceiver())
```

Comment: Your answer works. Is it possible to add tags or baggage to existing span?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it using Camel 3.7.0, but I am 2 years late to the question, so I hope this helps someone, and if there is a better way please post.

My goal was to create a child span of the existing span, and this is definitely different from the OpenTracing examples, as Camel seems to have it's own way to access the active span.

Step 1: get the Tracer from the Camel context

```
Set<Tracer> tracers = exchange.getContext().getRegistry().findByType(Tracer.class);

// There should only be one Tracer
Tracer camelTracer = null;
for (Tracer tracer : tracers) {
    camelTracer = tracer;
}
```

Step 2: get the active span from Camel

```
OpenTracingSpanAdapter adapter = (OpenTracingSpanAdapter) ActiveSpanManager.getSpan(exchange);

Span activeSpan = adapter.getOpenTracingSpan();
```

Step 3: create a child span

```
Span childSpan = camelTracer.buildSpan("operation name").asChildOf(activeSpan).start();

childSpan.log(ImmutableMap.of("thing", thing));
childSpan.setTag("error", true);

childSpan.finish();
```

Comment: in which package is this..OpenTracingSpanAdapter ..I can't see this while using camel 2.23.2

Comment: It does not exist in your version.  https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-opentracing/3.7.1/index.html